# Json string results number counting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, counting

I got this json string

```
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "Error": 0,
        "ErrorMessage": "No error",
        "Locale": "us_US",
        "Quality": 40,
        "Found": 2,
        "Results": [{
            "quality": 72,
            "latitude": "19.113130",
            "longitude": "72.873140",
            "woetype": 22
        }, {
            "quality": 72,
            "latitude": "19.094630",
            "longitude": "72.847460",
            "woetype": 22
        }]
    }
}
```

How do I get the number of groups (not sure of the proper term) under *ResultSet.Results* using JavaScript?

For instance, in the above example, it is 2, ie. `ResultSet.Results[0]` & `ResultSet.Results[1]`

```
"Results": [{
            "quality": 72,
            "latitude": "19.113130",
            "longitude": "72.873140",
            "woetype": 22
        }, {
            "quality": 72,
            "latitude": "19.094630",
            "longitude": "72.847460",
            "woetype": 22
        }]
```

Comment: Correct terminology would be the number of objects in the Results array.  Since it's an array, ResultSet.Results.length works perfectly as mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ResultSet.Results.length
```

This should work, as it is a normal array.